# CursorIndexOutOfBoundException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 1

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

How do i do a select statement which retrieves 2 String and 1 integer value. I am receiving this error. My app keep crashing at cursor.getString(0); In my log, i do get this message Log.d("TAG","Row found");

**Login.java**

```
private void getQRCodeInformation(){
    //database helper object
    DatabaseHelper db;
    //initializing views and objects
    db = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    Cursor cursor = db.getQRCodeInformation();
    if(cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Log.d("TAG","Nothing found");
    }
    else{
        Log.d("TAG","Row found");
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            //cursor.getString(0);
            //cursor.getString(1);
            //cursor.getInt(1);
            Log.d("TAG","Data found");
        }
    }
}
```

**DatabaseHelper.java**

```
public Cursor getQRCodeInformation(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT "+COLUMN_0_UserDetail+" , "+COLUMN_4_UserDetail+" , "+COLUMN_5_UserDetail+ " FROM "+ TABLE_NAME_UserDetail;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
    return c;
}
```

Comment: i have commented cursor.getString(0) to check my log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to get index of column

> int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME);

then

> String columnValue = cursor.getString(index);

Good luck :)

Comment: int index_pin = cursor.getColumnIndex("pin");
            int index_url = cursor.getColumnIndex("url");
            int index_auth = cursor.getColumnIndex("auth");
            String columnValue_pin = cursor.getString(index_pin);
            String columnValue_url = cursor.getString(index_url);
            String columnValue_auth = cursor.getString(index_auth);

Comment: if you have columns like "url", "auth" or "pin" yes, it is.